# django_python3_ldap TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'receive_timeout'

Tags: python, ldap, timeout, connection, openldap

I have a local app that is using the library `django_python3_ldap`and it's working fine. But when I deploy it to AWS elastic beanstalk, it throws an error saying that
 `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'receive_timeout'.`

I was suspecting that my company's firewall was blocking the access to the LDAP server, but then I asked IT to monitor attempt to connect to the LDAP server and they said they didn't see any connections. I am quite confused what the issue might be.

Here is the file where the issue occured from the `django_python3_ldap` library

```
class Connection(object):

    """
    A connection to an LDAP server.
    """

    def __init__(self, connection):
        """
        Creates the LDAP connection.
        No need to call this manually, the `connection()` context
        manager handles initialization.
        """
        self._connection = connection

    def _get_or_create_user(self, user_data):
        """
        Returns a Django user for the given LDAP user data.
        If the user does not exist, then it will be created.
        """

        attributes = user_data.get("attributes")
        if attributes is None:
            logger.warning("LDAP user attributes empty")
            return None

        User = get_user_model()

        # Create the user data.
        user_fields = {
            field_name: (
                attributes[attribute_name][0]
                if isinstance(attributes[attribute_name], (list, tuple)) else
                attributes[attribute_name]
            )
            for field_name, attribute_name
            in settings.LDAP_AUTH_USER_FIELDS.items()
            if attribute_name in attributes
        }
        user_fields = import_func(settings.LDAP_AUTH_CLEAN_USER_DATA)(user_fields)
        # Create the user lookup.
        user_lookup = {
            field_name: user_fields.pop(field_name, "")
            for field_name
            in settings.LDAP_AUTH_USER_LOOKUP_FIELDS
        }
        # Update or create the user.
        user, created = User.objects.update_or_create(
            defaults=user_fields,
            **user_lookup
        )
        # If the user was created, set them an unusable password.
        if created:
            user.set_unusable_password()
            user.save()
        # Update relations
        import_func(settings.LDAP_AUTH_SYNC_USER_RELATIONS)(user, attributes)
        # All done!
        logger.info("LDAP user lookup succeeded")
        return user

    def iter_users(self):
        """
        Returns an iterator of Django users that correspond to
        users in the LDAP database.
        """
        paged_entries = self._connection.extend.standard.paged_search(
            search_base=settings.LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE,
            search_filter=format_search_filter({}),
            search_scope=ldap3.SUBTREE,
            attributes=ldap3.ALL_ATTRIBUTES,
            get_operational_attributes=True,
            paged_size=30,
        )
        return filter(None, (
            self._get_or_create_user(entry)
            for entry
            in paged_entries
            if entry["type"] == "searchResEntry"
        ))

    def get_user(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Returns the user with the given identifier.
        The user identifier should be keyword arguments matching the fields
        in settings.LDAP_AUTH_USER_LOOKUP_FIELDS.
        """
        # Search the LDAP database.
        if self._connection.search(
            search_base=settings.LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE,
            search_filter=format_search_filter(kwargs),
            search_scope=ldap3.SUBTREE,
            attributes=ldap3.ALL_ATTRIBUTES,
            get_operational_attributes=True,
            size_limit=1,
        ):
            return self._get_or_create_user(self._connection.response[0])
        logger.warning("LDAP user lookup failed")
        return None


@contextmanager
def connection(**kwargs):
    """
    Creates and returns a connection to the LDAP server.
    The user identifier, if given, should be keyword arguments matching the fields
    in settings.LDAP_AUTH_USER_LOOKUP_FIELDS, plus a `password` argument.
    """
    # Format the DN for the username.
    format_username = import_func(settings.LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_USERNAME)
    kwargs = {
        key: value
        for key, value
        in kwargs.items()
        if value
    }
    username = None
    password = None
    if kwargs:
        password = kwargs.pop("password")
        username = format_username(kwargs)
    # Configure the connection.
    if settings.LDAP_AUTH_USE_TLS:
        auto_bind = ldap3.AUTO_BIND_TLS_BEFORE_BIND
    else:
        auto_bind = ldap3.AUTO_BIND_NO_TLS
    # Connect.
    try:
        c = ldap3.Connection(
            ldap3.Server(
                settings.LDAP_AUTH_URL,
                allowed_referral_hosts=[("*", True)],
                get_info=ldap3.NONE,
                connect_timeout=settings.LDAP_AUTH_CONNECT_TIMEOUT,
            ),
            user=username,
            password=password,
            auto_bind=auto_bind,
            raise_exceptions=True,
            receive_timeout=settings.LDAP_AUTH_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT,
        )
    except LDAPException as ex:
        logger.warning("LDAP connect failed: {ex}".format(ex=ex))
        yield None
        return
    # If the settings specify an alternative username and password for querying, rebind as that.
    if (
        (settings.LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_USERNAME or settings.LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_PASSWORD) and
        (
            settings.LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_USERNAME != username or
            settings.LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_PASSWORD != password
        )
    ):
        User = get_user_model()
        try:
            c.rebind(
                user=format_username({User.USERNAME_FIELD: settings.LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_USERNAME}),
                password=settings.LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_PASSWORD,
            )
        except LDAPException as ex:
            logger.warning("LDAP rebind failed: {ex}".format(ex=ex))
            yield None
            return
    # Return the connection.
    logger.info("LDAP connect succeeded")
    try:
        yield Connection(c)
    finally:
        c.unbind()


def authenticate(*args, **kwargs):
    """
    Authenticates with the LDAP server, and returns
    the corresponding Django user instance.
    The user identifier should be keyword arguments matching the fields
    in settings.LDAP_AUTH_USER_LOOKUP_FIELDS, plus a `password` argument.
    """
    password = kwargs.pop("password")
    # Check that this is valid login data.
    if not password or frozenset(kwargs.keys()) != frozenset(settings.LDAP_AUTH_USER_LOOKUP_FIELDS):
        return None
    # Connect to LDAP.
    with connection(password=password, **kwargs) as c:
        if c is None:
            return None
        return c.get_user(**kwargs)
```

I would really appreciate any input on any of the issues. Thanks again!

Comment: It might be a *ldap* version mismatch. Did you try commenting the line `receive_timeout=settings.LDAP_AUTH_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT,`?

Comment: @CristiFati I am currently deploying this to the aws elasticbeanstalk, So i don't think i would be able to directly access the library. But either way, I don't quite understand why this is working fine on my local but not when it's being deployed...

Comment: You might want to check the sources for `ldap3.Connection` (the initializer). But I imagine that you are deploying this (same) library on your machine and on *AWS* as well, so it's strange...

Comment: @CristiFati yes I am using the exact same libraries on my local and aws so I'm not sure why this error is occuring...

Comment: The `receive_timeout` argument exists in v1.1.2 and above of ldap3. It sounds as though your AWS deployment may have picked up an earlier version of ldap3.

Comment: @WillKeeling thanks for the inpu!, but i did indeed specify the version number of ldap3 on my requirements.txt file tho, do you know how I should attempt to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you able to run `pip show ldap3` from the command line of your production server?

Comment: @WillKeeling I tried to `eb ssh` into it and ran `pip show ldap3` it doesn't return any info so I assume it's not there somehow? I think what happened was that I accidentally installed `python3-ldap` before and that was what `ldap3` used to be called. Since I realized that I took `python3-ldap` off my `requirments.txt` but I guess it is still installed on the server and is being used?

Comment: Yes sounds plausible. Try running `pip uninstall python3-ldap` on the server to remove it.

Comment: @WillKeeling I uninstalled it and put `ldap3==2.3` in my requriements.txt file but now when I log in it says this error in django `No module named 'ldap3.core.exceptions'` I'm so confused I am certain that i installed the package

Comment: Are you sure your deployment process has installed the `requirements.txt`? If you run `pip show ldap3` what do you get?